# OpenContainer animation closed in same widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

First of all, so sorry for my english. So I use "**animations**" package to use Container transform animation. To be clear, i want to show stories in my app like instagram. For that i use "**story**" package also. I have horizontal listView to show stories. And i return OpenContainer widget in this listView's itemBuilder. So in OpenContainer, i return custom container inside closedBuilder and i return StoryPageView inside openBuilder. Everything works properly, but closing process. For example, i have 3 custom containers (or stories). When i click first one, animation works properly,but when stories finishes or i decide to close from second one, closing animation works in first one. Or when i click second story and decide to close from third one, also closing animation works in second one.

I try to set key to my custom containers (or stories). But it didn't work.

Here is the codes that include OpenContainer:

```
List<StoryModel> stories = state.storyList;
            return ListView.separated(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => 8.horizontalSpace,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return OpenContainer(
                  useRootNavigator: true,
                  closedBuilder: (context, action) {
                    return HorizontalImagesItem(
                      storyImageUrl: stories[index].stories[0].image,

                      
                    );
                  },
                  openBuilder: (context, action) => StoryPage(
                    storyList: stories,
                    storyPageIndex: index,
                
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: stories.length,
            );
```

Comment: Please share your code here for more references.

Comment: @PradipD. i edited post. Hope that it will help